# My ASP.NET MVC authentication sign out shortly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, host

I wrote an ASP.NET MVC web site and use authentication. I set a cookie like this

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName, login.RememberMe);
```

This cookie is created correctly, but user is signed out very soon.

This is my `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="LightOilManager" loginUrl="/Customer/Home/Login" defaultUrl="/" timeout="43200" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

I don't know how to fix this. I think it worked correctly in my localhost but I am not sure

I changed the timeout but it doesn't work.

I checked the cookie in the browser but it was created correctly.

I use plesk and change options but nothing happened

Comment: Have you written some custom logic to check for authentication or are you using the `Authorize` attribute? Also add the following attributes to your forms authentication settings: `slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All"`

Comment: If this is only happening to you in production be aware that the default session implementation in .NET is sever based. That means that if you have a "server farm" (i.e.: multiple servers serving the same app through a load balancer), the session will not be persisted across servers.

Answer (score 0):

due to solve this issue, you should increase the ram of your server or optimise your queries.

Best regards
Hossein

Comment: This answer is not correct. There is no direct correlation between session duration and how much RAM the server has. Maybe you should elaborate a little more?

Comment: @meryovi every session get a part of ram in server, due to increase user login, the ram has been overhoad so the web app will be restarted.  I Think he uses shared host. I got stuck with this problem many times.

Comment: @HosseinSafdari Yes I Use shared host